# What to do while application waits for event

Tags: c#

I have written the basis for a reminder application using c#/wpf.

I am wanting to notify the user by a popup of some sort when a reminder is active.

I am not to sure how to go about when the application is doing nothing while it waits for the next reminder to be active.

Any ideas or help is appreciated

Edit*

What class's i would use

Comment: As an example, `cron` calculates the length of time until it needs to "wake up" and do something, and then `sleep`s for that amount of time. You could do something similar, using `Timer`, etc.

Comment: Can you explain what is your problem more detailed?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

At your application startup and every time you add, change or delete a reminder, you look up the first existing reminder (in chronological order) and sets the timer to the time between now and the set reminder time.

When the timer callback is called you locate the correct reminder and act on it.